# How to add a specific number of silent samples to an audio file

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I am manipulating audio with pydub for use with video. I want to pad the end of an audio segment with silent frames so it fills a frame of video. At an audio sampling rate of 48kHz and a video sampling rate of 25 fps, I need each audio segment to have a multiple of 1920 samples (= 48 000 / 25).

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408458/pydub-slice-audio-segment-by-sample) to add silent samples at the end of a segment:

```py
import pydub

segment = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav("jingle.wav")
sampling_rate = segment.frame_rate
assert 48000 == sampling_rate
num_samples = len(segment.get_array_of_samples())

num_samples_to_add = 1920 - num_samples % 1920

silence = pydub.AudioSegment.silent(duration=1000, frame_rate=sampling_rate)
silence_samples = silence.get_array_of_samples()
silence_padding = silence._spawn(silence_samples[:num_samples_to_add])

padded = segment + silence_padding

print("Segment: %d samples, %dms" % (len(segment.get_array_of_samples()), len(segment)))
print("Silence: %d samples, %dms" % (len(silence_padding.get_array_of_samples()), len(silence_padding)))
print("Padded: %d samples, %dms" % (len(padded.get_array_of_samples()), len(padded)))

print("Padded should have %d frames instead of %d" % (num_samples + num_samples_to_add, len(padded.get_array_of_samples())))
```

The result is:

```
Segment: 230544 samples, 2402ms
Silence: 1776 samples, 37ms
Padded: 234096 samples, 2438ms
Padded should have 232320 frames instead of 234096
```

The number of milliseconds in the result is right, but the number of samples is not. The code worked on one WAV file but doesn't on [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hfxqry0kfwbehrad5sd08/jingle.wav?rlkey=idngfwaqi6cw0liy45wfwz1jf&dl=0). I suspect it's because of improper use of `._spawn`, but I could not find documentation and I cannot figure out why the  discrepancy between duration in seconds and in samples.

How can I add a specific number of silent samples at the end of an audio file?

Comment: Are the files you are dealing with all mono? `234096` is `230544 + (1776*2)` i.e. the length of your sample plus the length of silence multiplied by `2`. That would suggest the silence is being doubled. What you  likely want is `padded.frame_count()`. In stereo each "frame" will contain `2` samples

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Indeed, some files are stereo. Can you please write an answer with `frame_count()`, which makes the code more robust?

Comment: It looks like pydub spreads a mono silence across  as many channels of sources, which means it actually does all work and is robust, unless something else isn’t working that is.